# Drush 8.0.3 cannot update custom module

Tags: drush

I have a few custom modules that updates are being served from a D6 site with the [Feature Server (fserver)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fserver) module. Before updating drush, the drush up command on a site would see there were updates for them just fine. Now I get:

```
$ drush up uni_blocks_antares
Update information last refreshed: Mon, 03/07/2016 - 09:13
Name                Installed Version  Proposed version  Message               
uni_blocks_antares  Unknown            Unknown           Specified project not 
                                                         found                 


No code updates available.                                           [ok]
```

But when I check that module's info it exists.

```
$ drush pmi uni_blocks_antares
Extension        :  uni_blocks_antares                                        
Project          :  uni_blocks_antares                                        
Type             :  module                                                    
Title            :  UNI Blocks Antares                                        
Description      :  This module pulls in the feed of Toolbar and Footer links 
                    from the UNI Features website and creates blocks          
                    containing those links.                                   
Version          :  7.x-2.7                                                   
Package          :  UNI Custom Modules                                        
Core             :  7.x                                                       
PHP              :  5.2.4                                                     
Status           :  enabled                                                   
Path             :  sites/all/modules/custom/uni_blocks_antares               
Schema version   :  module has no schema                                      
Files            :  none                                                      
Requires         :  none                                                      
Required by      :  none                                                      
Permissions      :  none                                                      
Configure        :  admin/config/content/uni-blocks
```

I found that updating through the web interface of the site will see an update(version 2.8) and update the module.

How do I get drush up to work again for it?

Comment: Is this a module on drupal.org?

Comment: No, it is just on one of our sites using the Feature Server module to manage the project and releases.

Comment: I think I found a solution to my problem! There is a patch for drush 8 to fix the handling of the project status url https://www.drupal.org/node/2043513. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was updating drush to 8.0.5 and that solved it.